# многопоточность с Future

Tags: java, многопоточность

у меня самый долгий поток не даёт вывести отработавшие фьючерсы, допустим я запускаю метот test в 4 потока первых 3 зависают на 1 сек, а 4й на 10сек и вот пока 4 поток не отработает фьючер ничего не выведет, хотя следующие три потока заполнит работой.

Вывод:

```
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 10000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 10000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
```

а мне бы хотелось узнать, как это можно исправить на такой результат:

```
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 1000
sleep: 10000
sleep: 10000
```

Немного кода:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TEEE testClass = TEEE.getInstance();
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
    integers.add(1000);
    integers.add(1000);
    integers.add(1000);
    integers.add(10000);
    integers.add(1000);
    integers.add(1000);
    integers.add(1000);
    integers.add(1000);
    integers.add(10000);
    integers.add(1000);
    integers.add(1000);
    integers.add(1000);
    integers.add(1000);
    integers.forEach(x -> futures.add(executorService.submit(() -> testClass.test(x))));
    futures.forEach(x -> {
        try {
            System.out.println("sleep: " + x.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
public class TEEE {
   private static TEEE instance;
   public Integer test(Integer in) {
     try {
        Thread.sleep(Long.valueOf(in));

     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return in;
    }
   public static TEEE getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new TEEE();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

}

Comment: я не оч сильно разбираюсь, но мне кажется вы сами себя блокируете во тут `x.get()`

Comment: @tym32167 а как мне результат выводить?

Comment: futures.parallelStream().forEach -> мне это помогло, но хорошо ли это???, да чуть по ресурсам бульше стало бить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы в цикле пробуете получить результат выполнения `Future` с помощью блокирующего вызова `get`. Он ждет, когда результат будет готов.

Нужно либо делать [неблокирующий](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) вызов либо проверять [завершилась](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()) ли задача, перед тем как пробовать читать результат.

Но лучше всего воспользоваться [CompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionService.html).

Он позволяет завернуть обычный `Executor` и ему так же как и обычному executor-у можно давать задачи, но при этом можно ждать когда следующая задача завершилась

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
CompletionService <Integer> completionService = 
       new ExecutorCompletionService<Integer>(executorService);

completionService.sumbit(() -> ...);
completionService.sumbit(() -> ...);


Future<Integer> resultFuture;

# poll блокируется пока не будет готов результат
while ((resultFuture = completionService.poll()) != null) {
  try {            
    System.out.println("sleep: " + resultFuture.get());
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ExecutionException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
};
```

Comment: for(Future future: futures) {
            try {
                Integer result = completionService.take().get();
                System.out.println("sleep: " + result);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

Спасибо за помощь, чуть исправил)